# CAS Apereo 6.1.x importing PasswordEncoderUtils

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management, cas

I am trying to build a project using CAS open source library and I encountered an error while trying to use PasswordEncoderUtils https://github.com/apereo/cas/blob/6.1.x/core/cas-server-core-authentication-api/src/main/java/org/apereo/cas/authentication/support/password/PasswordEncoderUtils.java

I have imported the following dependency to my build.gradle

```
dependencies {      
runtimeOnly group: 'org.apereo.cas', name: 'cas-server-core-authentication-api', version: '6.1.4'
}
```

However, when in my main class im trying to import

```
import org.apereo.cas.authentication.support.password.PasswordEncoderUtils;
```

The import of PasswordEncoderUtils was not found. Please help me figure this out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you refresh / assemble gradle after adding this dependency ?

Comment: Yes, I have added other dependencies as well and their import statement worked except for this particular one

Answer (score 0):

I think its the use of `runtimeOnly` which make it unavailable because its not in your compile classpath .

and am quoting from [official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency_configurations)

> runtimeOnly:
>
> Gradle adds the dependency to the build output only, for use during
> runtime. That is, it is not added to the compile classpath. This
> configuration behaves just like apk (which is now deprecated).

I think if you want to use it in your code , changing to implementation will fix the issue .